# OSGi custom shell command

Tags: eclipse, osgi, equinox

I am trying to create a custom command for the OSGI console (Equinox) but I cannot seem to either register or use the command correctly. The bundle starts and tried to call `mock:command` or `command` to no avail. The used eclipse is rather old: 3.6.2.R36x_v20110210 and the containing bundle is started manually. Any ideas?

```
public class Activator extends Plugin
{
    private static Activator plugin;
    private MockCommand service;

    @Override
    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception{
        plugin = this;  
        Dictionary<String, Object> properties = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
        properties.put("osgi.command.scope", "mock");
        properties.put("osgi.command.function", new String[] {MockCommand.COMMAND});
        service =  new MockCommand();
        context.registerService(MockCommand.class.getName(),service, null);
        super.start(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception{
        plugin = null;
        service = null;
        super.stop(context);
    }

    public static Activator getDefault(){
        return plugin;
    }
}
```

And the CommandProvider:

```
public class MockCommand implements CommandProvider{

    public static String COMMAND ="command";

    public void _command(CommandInterpreter ci) throws Exception {
        String commandID = "com.sample.project.fetchMySampleDataCommandId";
        ((IHandlerService)PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IHandlerService.class)).executeCommand(commandID, null);
    }

    @Override
    public String getHelp() {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        buffer.append("--- Available commands to call by ID ---\n\t");
        buffer.append("command --> com.sample.project.fetchMySampleDataCommandId\n\t");
        return buffer.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There was apparently an OSGI Service-Component definition missing. In order to do that I created an /OSGI-INF/ServiceFacade.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" name="serviceFacade">
    <implementation class="com.sample.project.MockCommand"/>
    <service>
        <provide interface="org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console.CommandProvider"/>
    </service>
</scr:component>
```

and added to my /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

```
Service-Component: OSGI-INF/ServiceFacade.xml
```